# Contracts inheriting each other

Tags: solidity

I know this. Most likely isn't possible but can 2 contracts inherit each other?

Example:
ContractA has varA and functionA
ContractB has varB and FunctionB

ContractA needs functionB for functionA to work

ContractB needs varA and varB for functionB to work for functionA

That's a really bad example but I think it kinda explains my question

Comment: Why not just declare varA in the contractB then? Of course it is not possible because it would create a short circuit as in all programming languages. I mean circuit dependencies. Also, check remix.ethereum.org. You can play here with whatever idea you have in mind.

Comment: I use remix a lot. I'm just trying to figure out how to do something without adding more functions to the main contract.